# Gnuplot key: Force uneven split

Tags: gnuplot

I have four curves to plot. The first three are variants of each other, the fourth one is distinct. Hence, I would like the key to split in 3+1. However, using e.g.

```
set key maxrows 3
plot sin(x),sin(2*x),sin(3*x),exp(x)
```

gives a two-row key.

Can I force gnuplot to split the key in three+one?

Comment: Ugly hack: `set key maxrows 3; plot sin(x),sin(2*x),sin(3*x), exp(x), NaN ti " "  w l lc rgb "white"`

Comment: @user8153 haha, yep! I tried plotting NaN, but didn't think of white lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @user8153's solution, I would like to suggest a slightly more general solution.
What if you have a colored background? For example: `set term wxt background rgb "grey90"` or if
you have a colored key (or legend) box... hmm, well, gnuplot doesn't offer an option for
colored background of the key box. Well, then if you put a colored rectangle behind the key.
Of course you can always adapt the color to the background, but I guess it would be simpler to plot an invisible line with `lt -2` or `lt nodraw`.

About `lt -2` or `lt nodraw`, I just learned a few days ago here: [gnuplot: why is linewidth 0 not zero in width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61684554/7295599). It's not (yet) in the manual, although it seems to be around since gnuplot version 5.0.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=4.6.7)

```
### invisible keyentry for column/row arrangement
reset

set key top left maxrows 3
set obj 1 rect from graph 0.02,0.82 to graph 0.52,0.98 fs solid 1.0 fc rgb "grey90"
set xrange[-2:2]
set yrange[-2:2]

plot sin(x), sin(2*x), sin(3*x), exp(x), NaN lt -2 ti " "
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Actually, I forgot that there is a workaround for a colored background of the keybox. No manual adjustment and fiddling around with the box:
[Set custom background color for key in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58577151/7295599)

***Update:*** as of gnuplot 5.4.4 there is an option for a colored background of the key box (check `help key`)

In case you want a transparent background, e.g. for images on webpages using, e.g. pngcairo, pdfcairo, etc., besides `lt -2` or `lt nodraw`, another solution would be to plot a transparent line, e.g. transparent "black" `lc rgb 0xff000000`:

```
plot sin(x), sin(2*x), sin(3*x), exp(x), NaN lc rgb 0xff000000 ti " "
```

**Script:**

```
### invisible keyentry for column/row arrangement with transparent background
reset session

set term pngcairo transparent
set output "SO51358774.png"

set key top left maxrows 3
set xrange[-2:2]
set yrange[-2:2]

plot sin(x), sin(2*x), sin(3*x), exp(x), NaN lt -2 ti " "
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:** (shown in front of checkerboard pattern)

[image]